# Select and file input form data in flask

Tags: html, forms, flask, file-upload, html-select

So I have this flask website that I can upload files to but I want them to be uploaded into separate folders depending on a drop down list in the same form.
So basically I want it to function that if I pick option "level1" in the form, the file should be uploaded to the level1 subdirectory and if I pick "level2" it should upload to the level2 directory etc.

I started out by adding both the select and input file into the same form but only the file upload is happening and I don't seem to get any value from the select part of the form when printing the details of request.form, request.values, request.data etc.

Likely there is something I am missing with the logic here, perhaps I cannot use select int the same form as file input due to the enctype?
I am not seeing the select part of the form data in the browser either when looping at the dev console.

Comment: looks as if there is something missing in the code part as well. Yes, you can get the value of select and upload the image in the same form. Please update with your .py file and html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I was not seeing the data was because I missed the name attribute in the select tag. Stupid mistake...